# MS SQL: Update only if data record does not exist

Tags: sql-server, conditional-statements

I have an MSSQL table with the following columns:

```
ID (int, unique), Name (varchar), Hobby (varchar)
```

The "Hobby" column allows NULL values.
The table has these data sets (as an example):

```
1, "John Doe", null
2, "Jack Doe", "racing"
3, "Mary Doe", "running"
4, "Mike Doe", null
5, "Mike Doe", "skiing"
```

I now want to do the following:
Replace null values with "chilling" in the "Hobby" column for which there is not already another data row present w/o null.
In pseudo-code I want to do this:

```
UPDATE table SET Hobby = "chilling" WHERE Hobby is null and <nobody with the same name has a hobby already>
```

This means that the data row 1 should be affected, however the data row 5 should not be (to avoid duplicates).

My colleagues and I have pondered over this question for quite some time now and cannot find a solution.

How can I create the SQL statement which does what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE t1
SET Hobby = "chilling" 
FROM table t1
WHERE Hobby IS NULL
AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM Table t2
    WHERE t2.Name = t1.Name
    AND t2.Hobby IS NOT NULL
)
```

### Update:

```
UPDATE tablename t1
SET Hobby = 'chilling' 
FROM t1
WHERE Hobby IS NULL
AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM tablename t2
    WHERE t2.Name = t1.Name
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Zohar's answer works, except a few misspellings in the code:

```
UPDATE tablename t1
SET Hobby = 'chilling' 
FROM t1
WHERE Hobby IS NULL
AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM tablename t2
    WHERE t2.Name = t1.Name
    AND t2.Hobby IS NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: One more thing: If I have multiple duplicates of row 1, they will all get the "chilling" value. I did not specify this clearly in my question but I do not want this behavior. I only want one of the "row 1" entries to get the chilling hobby.